# Is it possible to grow brain tissue in vitro? Can we make a super-brain this way?

Tags: human-biology, brain

I wonder whether such experiments were conducted? Is it possible to create a "biological super-computer" this way?

Comment: Hi, this is John from the ethics committee at your local university. Please meet me tomorrow at 9 PM at my office so that we can further discuss the details of your oncoming experiment.

Comment: can you specify what you mean by "brain tissue"? it is possible to culture stem cells to neurons. It is possible to create organoids (artificial collection of several tissues).

Comment: More importantly, you currently asking two questions: is it possible to create artificial brain, and is it possible to use such brain as super computer. COnsider asking two separate questions instead

Answer (score 2):

This is actually not an unheard of idea among neuroscientists and is an aspect of much research.  Brains in general have amazing computational powers and abilities that allow them to circumvent the limitations of computation which is usually based on a Turing Machine. Neurons pursue highly parallel architectures and exhibit cognition or even emotions or do highly sensitive signal processing, which has heretofore been unapproachable with computational methods such as Machine Learning.

As such many researchers are focused on understanding the brain or at least the brain's structure to augment or produce computation.  Here are a couple of examples of neuron arrays [flying virtual](https://www.newscientist.com/article/dn6573-brain-cells-in-a-dish-fly-fighter-plane/) or [real drones](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yJirHaBj3Vw)....

The ethical issues aren't great concerns because neural cell networks can be encouraged to grow differentiating from easy to grow cell lines like fibroblasts.

Another approach to augmented computing is to interface directly into a living brain. Model [brain organoids](https://www.stemcell.com/technical-resources/area-of-interest/organoid-research/neural-organoids/overview.html) are a popular topic of interest and could one day be used to interface to other computational systems.  There are of course many devices that try to interface to the brain via electrical fields in the same way EEGs work.

there are [connectome](http://portal.brain-map.org/) projects that are trying to understand the neural connections between cells that are so important to brain development, with the theory that the topology of these networks might enable even computers to perform like brains.

Comment: Moore's Law of computation (which was in no way a law) was an observation of a trend in the fabrication of computor memory). Unless your brain is receiving upgrades from Intel every two years, your statement would seem difficult to understand.

Comment: fixed this in edit